# Generating a list of edges in neo4j from a variable length path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to generate a list of edges to read into an R dataframe for use in the vizNetwork package. This has to be, in its most simple format, as a table with 2 columns, "from" and "to".

In [the neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/), the default query that pops up pretty much illustrates the type of query I am trying to run in that a starting point is specified then the resulting chain is the graph I'm interested in.

The query that is run is `match (n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS*]-(m) where n.name='Neo' return n as Neo,r,m` and this returns a graph showing the chain of relationships and also a table that I have included below.

```
Neo                   r                                                            m
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"}) [(0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1)]                                         (1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"}) [(0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1), (1)-[2:KNOWS]->(2)]                     (2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"}) [(0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1), (1)-[3:KNOWS]->(3)]                     (3:Crew:Matrix {name:"Cypher"})
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"}) [(0)-[0:KNOWS]->(1), (1)-[3:KNOWS]->(3), (3)-[4:KNOWS]->(4)] (4:Matrix {name:"Agent Smith"})
```

The table doesn't contain the edges in a very "edgy" format. How can I make that relationship graph return the results in the following format...

```
from         to
Neo          Morpheus
Morpheus     Trinity
Morpheus     Cypher
Cypher       Agent Smith
```

Nicole White wrote [a guide on integrating rneo4j and vizNetwork](https://nicolewhite.github.io/examples/visNetwork/rneo4j-visnetwork.html) but this relied on generating the node list first then referencing the ids of the resulting list as a parameter in the edge list query. I was hoping to achieve a "pure cypher" method if possible.

Comment: Since you only want a pure Cypher answer, you shouldn't use the `r` tag. You should ask a separate question later for how to process it in r if it becomes relevant later.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. Best not cause confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row you want to return is 1 edge. So to get the return you want, just match on the edge and Neo4j will create a row for every valid occurrence of that pattern.

```
MATCH (from)-[:KNOWS]->(to)
RETURN from.name as from, to.name as to
```

You can than filter that using WHERE pattern matching like so

```
MATCH (from)-[:KNOWS]->(to)
WHERE (:Person {name:"Neo"})-[:KNOWS*..25]->(from)
RETURN from.name as from, to.name as to
```

Comment: That did it. They only thing missing was the neo to morpheus relationship but I can union that on. Thanks @Tezra.

Comment: @dopple Well, technically, you shouldn't need the union if you change `from` to `to` in the WHERE clause